# Open a jar, either by cooling or heating

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, thermal-conductivity

I've found this question online and don't agree with the explanation given.

> There’s a tight lid on a jar that you need to get loose. The lid on this jar is made of wood and is supposed to unscrew from the jar — if only it wasn't stuck. The coefficient of thermal expansion of the glass jar is higher than that of the wood lid.
> How can you make the lid easier to remove?

Explanation

> If you heat the lid and the jar, then the jar will expand more than the lid does — which would make the lid of the jar even tighter and more difficult to open.

> If you cool the lid and the jar, then the jar will contract more than the lid does, leaving the lid relatively large compared to the jar and easier to remove.

I disagree. If you heat the jar, the diameter of the top opening increases more than the diameter of the wooden lid, making it looser. The opposite happen if you cool the jar and the lid.
Can you please clarify what's happening?

Comment: It depends on the geometry. Is the lid inside tha jar, like a cork in a bottle?

Comment: yes, I think it's inside

Comment: Then it would not be a lid. It would be a cork or a stopper. From the description it is clear that the wooden lid has a lip with a thread outside the jar.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: A jar lid fastens to the outside of the opening. That's why when the opening expands it grips the lid more tightly. Google for pictures of jars to see this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the points of contact between the wooden lid (not a stopper or a cork) and the glass jar the "diameter" of each material is the same.

Since for a given temperature decrease the fractional reduction in diameter of wood will be less than that of the glass it will be easier to remove the lid when they are cooled.

This is the opposite of trying to open a glass jar with a metal lid (coefficient of expansion greater than that of glass) when one method is to put the lid (and jar) under a stream of hot water.

Comment: In the case of glass jar with metal lid. In almost all cases: in the factory the lid is closed with the lid, jar, and jar contents very hot. (Close to boiling point to ensure the contents are sterilized.) When the jar has cooled down the inside pressure is far lower. As a consequence atmospheric pressure is pushing the lid onto the jar, which increases jar-lid friction. Heating the lid and the jar increases the inside pressure. Equalized pressure leads to less jar-lid friction. In everyday life I expect the pressure equalization to be the primary factor.

Comment: A very good point but I was referring to a jar which already been opened.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to explain mathematically. Normally, coefficient of linear thermal expansion is expressed as:
$$\alpha=\frac{dl}{ldT}$$
$l$ is original length, $\alpha$ is our coefficient of linear thermal expansion.
$dT$ is change in temperature.

Or we can write it approximately as:
$$\Delta l=l\alpha \Delta T$$
$$l_f=l_o(1+\alpha \Delta T)$$

Now given is $\alpha_{wood}<\alpha_{glass}...(1)$

Logically for loosening lid, we need $R_{wood}>R_{glass}$(radius)
If we cooled:
$$R_{wood}=R(1-\alpha_{wood} \Delta T)$$
$$R_{glass}=R(1-\alpha_{glass} \Delta T)$$
Using $(1)$:

$R_{wood}>R_{glass}$

We achieved our objective.

Now if we do opposite:
$R_{wood}<R_{glass}$
So lid will only get tighter, and lid may break once enough shear stress is generated. Shear stress generated from expansion by applying stress causes potential energies to be stored inside like a spring, which makes lid tighter.

Hope it helps